# How to resolve CursorIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This has stumped me so far.

I keep getting a CursorIndexOutOfBounds when trying to run a this specific query.

```
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id='2'" , null);
```

But the odd thing is above that query I am running a loop that outputs all of the _id values from that table. It outputs 1 to 100 so I know that the value is there. Also I output all of the columns and they are all there as I expect.

Even though I am pretty sure there are values and in the correct columns this line of code keeps thowing the CursorIndexOutOfBounds. Could anyone suggest avenues to approach this problem.

```
    numval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

Logcat entry

```
11-21 11:35:09.367: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11664): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

EDIT

Here is the exact code I am running. I am still getting the error I posted just above this sentence.

```
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table" , null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {

        numval = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String numvalval = Integer.toString(numval);
        Log.e("RESULT",numvalval);
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();
    Cursor ti = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(table)", null);
    if ( ti.moveToFirst() ) {
        do {
            Log.e("COLUMN NAMES","col: '" + ti.getString(1) +"'");
        } while (ti.moveToNext());
    }
    ti.close();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id='2'" , null);
    c.moveToFirst();
                numval      = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

It is outputting

```
11-21 13:27:25.906: ERROR/RESULT(13377): 1
11-21 13:27:25.906: ERROR/RESULT(13377): 2
11-21 13:27:25.910: ERROR/COLUMN NAMES(13377): col: '_id'
11-21 13:27:25.910: ERROR/COLUMN NAMES(13377): col: 'country'
```

Comment: Try using Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id=?" , new String[] {"2"});

Comment: I would advice against using "SELECT *", it really makes the code harder to grasp. Specify which columns to select.

Comment: @sandis what should i be using instead?

Comment: @Max use for example "SELECT column1, column2, column3", so you see which column you have selected and in what order. "SELECT *" will become chaotic when the database grows :P

Answer (score 2):

***See edit, the following advice is not valid anymore after you edited question.***

When you get an `Cursor` object, in the beginning you should always move it to the first row. So your code should be like this:

```
if(c.moveToFirst()) {
    numval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
}
else {
    /* SQL Query returned no result ... */
}
```

**EDIT**
Change your query to this(without quotes around '2'):

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id=2" , null);
```

Comment: thanks. It didn't seem to change things. Is that a better way to run the query anyway?

Comment: Your right. Thank you so much! Why did that make a difference. It has been working fine up until now with single quotes

Comment: O wait im not sure this is actually solved. Let me test again

Answer (score 0):

It means that your accessing that index which is not there,   `numval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));`   First thing first check  your cursor is null or not `if(c==null)` or `if(c.getCount>0)`.

Comment: this is what is confusing me. As just before that query I output all of the id's into logcat and their is a 2

Comment: numval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")); 
you are passing here  "_id" as String, try with some int value..

Comment: try this Log.v(tag, "Result: " +cur.getColumnIndex("_id")); Log.v(tag, "Result: " +c.getColumnIndex("_id"));  If they return -1 thn  there is no column of "_id"

Comment: I will try this but from the code above you can see I do call _id successfully beforehand and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `c.moveToFirst();` before  `numval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
```

is not the correct approach

```
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
```

is

Also, Cursor has more specific methods tahn rawQuery, you should use these

Comment: thanks for the advice, these two things wouldnt affect the cursorindexoutofbounds error i am getting though. Am i right?

Comment: the moveToNext guaranties you that after calling it you are at a valid position in the cursor. isAfterLast may be true when isBeforeFirst is false.